# Отправка многомерного массива js через ajax post с получением обработанного результата

Tags: javascript, ajax

Доброго времени! Тут на сайте есть похожие ответы но они к сожалению не подошли мне т.к. у меня идет отправка многомерного массива записанного в подготовленную переменную и так же нужно получение ответа при успехе

вот такая функция

```
function gotolok (ids,tim,parms) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "gwcontrol/ajx/getlocation.php",
    data: "ids=" + ids + "&tim=" + tim + "&parms=" + parms,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(html){

        var ito = html.par1;//итог
        alert(ito); 
    }
}); 
}
```

в переменную parms передается массив - он может быть обычным или многомерным
для первого теста я пока использую обычный
такой

```
var ser = [
'ujdyb','drisnya','xuy'
];

 gotolok ('1','2',ser);
```

в файле обработчике parms обрабатывается через foreach и раскладывается а нужном порядке - пока для теста я поставил что бы они записывались в строку и выдавались мне Алертом. Но именно массив сейчас не передается в обработчик, как его нужно правильно передавать?

Comment: Его нужно сюреализовать `JSON.stringify(ser)`

Comment: @OlmerDale отлично это то что нужно я так и подумал что как то надо задать какой то тип особый для этих данных но не знал какой. Преобразуйте пожалуйста свой комментарий в ответ что бы я его мог пометить как правильный

Comment: ответьте сами на свой вопрос, только предварительно прочтите вот эту маленькую статью https://learn.javascript.ru/json вдруг будет что-то добавить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, перед отправкой данные переменной parms надо перевести в через JSON.stringify(ser) как подсказал [@OlmerDale](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220409/olmerdale)

```
ser = JSON.stringify(ser);
```

ну от себя добавлю что потом в обработчике надо будет преобразовать обратно в php массив так

```
$obj = json_decode($parms);
```